# ¿Qué es ''-> pd.DataFrame '' añadidio a la definición de una función?

Tags: python-3.7

Ya van varias veces que me encuentro scripts en los que se definen funciones y sus parámetros, de la siguiente manera,

```
def get_data(url: str,start_date: str) -> pd.DataFrame :
```

¿Qué parámetros debo incluir en la llamada para que opere correctamente? Intento esto.

```
url = '"https://...'
start_date = '2016-1-4
def get_data(url ,start_date)  :
```

Pero me devuelve el error 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

¿Que es '-> pd.DataFrame ' añadido a la definición de la función?.

Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: Solo es una indicación del valor de retonrno de esa función. Una indicación para el *usuario* (tú), que `python` internamente no usa para nada: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html ¿ Seguro que eso es lo que quieres preguntar ?

Comment: y, 'url: str,start_date: str' es una forma de indicarme que url y strat_date, deben ser strings?.

Comment: Correcto. Justamente eso, ni mas ni menos.

Comment: A pesar de esas indicaciones, es posible pasar algo que, en este caso,  no sea string. Incluso tu función podría funcionar bien solo por que el objeto pasado se parece a un string, pero no lo es. Este concepto es llamado [duck typing](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). "Si nada como pato, camina como pato y grasna como pato, es un pato"